# Kotlin list of vs array of

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference of these two snippets of code? And how to decide which one to use?

```
var array = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
```

and

```
var list = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)
```

With both codes I could access it by its index like this

```
println(array[0]) // Outputs 1  
println(list[0]) // Outputs 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the datatype:

```
var array = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)  --> class kotlin.Array
var list = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)    --> class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
```

You have to decide which data type fits your needs the best.